# how get rows with latest date?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have this table in BigQuery

```
country, date, confirmed    
Afghanistan, 2020-03-16, 21
Afghanistan, 2020-03-17, 22
Afghanistan, 2020-03-18, 22
Albania, 2020-03-16, 23
Albania, 2020-03-17, 33
Albania, 2020-03-18, 38
...
```

and I would like to show all rows per country with latest date,
however this command not working >

SELECT *  FROM table where date=max(date) > *Aggregate function MAX not allowed in WHERE clause at.*

output should be:

```
Afghanistan, 2020-03-18, 22
Albania, 2020-03-18, 38
```

Any idea pls ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT AS VALUE ARRAY_AGG(t ORDER BY day DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)]
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
GROUP BY country
```

if to apply to sample data from your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'Afghanistan' country, DATE '2020-03-16' day, 21 confirmed UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Afghanistan', '2020-03-17', 22 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Afghanistan', '2020-03-18', 22 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Albania', '2020-03-16', 23 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Albania', '2020-03-17', 33 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Albania', '2020-03-18', 38 
)
SELECT AS VALUE ARRAY_AGG(t ORDER BY day DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)]
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
GROUP BY country
```

output is

```
Row country         day         confirmed    
1   Afghanistan     2020-03-18  22   
2   Albania         2020-03-18  38
```

Comment: Ok, this works, but what if I have thousand or million rows already in DB ? why I must load the DATA/table   again manually ?
...WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'Afghanistan' country, DATE '2020-03-16' day, 21 confirmed UNION ALL....`
There is no simple way to filter it from my table ?

Comment: I loaded data to my original table from csv file

Comment: I am not sure what you are saying! have you tried the query against your table? the first query - the one without WITH. the query with WITH is just an example for quick test

Comment: Thx for help Mik, sorry for that, yep it working now :)

Comment: May I ask you how works this syntax ?
SELECT AS VALUE ARRAY_AGG(t ORDER BY day DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)]
FROM `project.dataset.table` t

Specialy the `t` letter in this query, I was looking on the web, but not found any good explanation how it works
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aggregate_functions

Comment: having alias t for the table then allows you to easily reference each and every row (the whole row as a struct) in your select statement. in this case it was use in `ARRAY_AGG(t ...)` . that alias can be any like ttt, or abc etc.

Comment: aah, this is alias, ok, anyway where can I mark it / accept this resolution ?
I dont see any button

Comment: This is such an odd syntax.  I don't disagree that this solution works, but it seems like there must be a better way to do this.

Comment: @Mr.LanceESloan - surprisingly, this is the best option for BigQuery SQL I am aware of :o)

Answer (score 1):

As I commented on the accepted solution to this question, there must be a better syntax than the one used in that solution.

The following solution works for me.  It may not be the most elegant, efficient, or "best" solution, but it is easy to understand.

```sql
# ---- begin example data
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'Afghanistan' country, DATE '2020-03-16' day, 21 confirmed UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Afghanistan', '2020-03-17', 22 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Afghanistan', '2020-03-18', 22 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Albania', '2020-03-16', 23 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Albania', '2020-03-17', 33 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Albania', '2020-03-18', 38 
)
# ---- end example data
# ---- begin query
SELECT *
FROM `project.dataset.table` AS t
WHERE t.`day`=(SELECT max(t.`day`) FROM `project.dataset.table` AS t)
GROUP BY t.country, t.`day`, t.confirmed
# ---- end query
```

It uses a subquery to find the maximum date and use that in the `where` clause of the main query.

I tried to produce a self-contained example with data as the accepted solution did.  However, the subquery was unable to access the data provided by the `WITH` clause.  There may be a better way to structure the example, but at least this query works and is easier to understand.

Comment: how about - per country? as it is in question :o)

Comment:  Thanks for asking.  I'll give an update soon.  I had based my query on the one given in the question.  I glossed over the details.

Comment: This solution works also best if you don't want to limit the rows returned to 1. For example in my case i don't want to return only 1 result of that date, but actually 100 results of that day per country. When using the subquery it actually returns this. When using ARRAY_AGG it only returns 1 row per country.

Comment: To others testing this query: Please note that when changing last select in with-clause to `SELECT 'Albania', '2020-03-19', 38`, query will return just `Albania`